# (Edited)Different meaning to それで

Tags: meaning, translation, manga

I read a manga and I saw that it was translated to “is that so oh well.” Sokka sorede” even if he continued speaking as if “sorede” meant “that’s why/because of that” as I understood the word. Is there any context sorede can mean “oh well” or was it a mistranslation?

Comment: @naruto https://kumacdn.club/wp-content/uploads/S/Shingeki%20no%20Kyojin/Chapter%20110/006.jpg 

It’s from the dialogue in the middle of the page

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the original text. The man says "ああそうかい それで", not "そっか".

- `そっか、それで!` means "Ah, so that's why!"
- `ああそうかい。それで...` means "I see, fine. So..." or "Okay, fair enough. So..."

Since it's a manga, punctuation marks are not shown, but the intended meaning is the latter.

(ああ)そっか indicates the speaker just understood something, whereas (ああ)そうかい indicates the speaker heard something but is not very interested. It's そうかい that corresponds to "oh well". Here それで just means "So" used to go back to the main topic or move on to the next topic.

Comment: The “so” doesn’t mean “therefore”?

Comment: @Uma No it doesn't. This それで is "so" as in "Nice to meet you. *So*, how did you know him?" or "I was studying all the day. *So*, what did you do yesterday?". It's used to change to a new topic.